# In Xcode 5, why don't UITextViews display their text in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, uitextview

In older versions of Xcode (pre Xcode 5) my UITextViews display their text in the Storyboard. In Xcode 5 the UITextViews are blue, labeled "UITextView" in white and the text is not displayed until runtime. I assume their is a preference somewhere to force the issue but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Um... how would the IDE be supposed to display the text at compilation time that will only be known at runtime?

Comment: In Xcode 5, when I paste a paragraph of text on the IB edit box for the UITextView it displays in the edit box but not on the Storyboard as it does in previous versions of Xcode. Sounds crazy but the text simply does not show on the Storyboard UITextView until runtime. That makes it difficult to positionally add objects on top of the UITextView, like a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you double tap your UITextFields in the interface builder you can edit the text, which will be displayed in your Storyboard. But if the text of your UITextField is set programatically the text will not be displayed in the Interface builder.

Comment: In Xcode 5, when I paste a paragraph of text on the IB edit box for the UITextView it displays in the edit box but not on the Storyboard as it does in previous versions of Xcode. Sounds crazy but the text simply does not show on the Storyboard UITextView until runtime. That makes it difficult to positionally add objects on top of the UITextView, like a checkbox.

Comment: I am facing same issue..While designing pages which includes lots of static text its very hard to put things together in the interface builder??Has anyone found solution yet?? Really desperate to know

Comment: @I noticed if you check the `editable` box in the `attributes inspector` of the `UITextView` it seems to fill it out? The problem for me is I don't want mine to be editable. Did you find a solution?